# photoshop - Set selection to transparency channel of layer

Tags: photoshop-effects, actions

I am trying to stepping a photoshop action, and I am confused when I get to this step: `Set selection to: transparency channel of layer "layername"`.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop you can ctrl+click on a layer thumbnail to set the selection to layer's alpha channel. That is the action described by this step.